# Verifying hosted Azure App Service's disk encryption status?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-security, azure-vm, azure-disk

I'm trying to get the encryption status of the disk where my App Service is hosted.

As per my understanding, App Services are hosted in some VMs in Azure. So I wanted to check the App Service hosted VM's encryption status. Currently i tried the below Azure CLI cmdlets, but its not able to find the VM host. I got the host name from kudu console within the App Service Azure portal.

```
--Get the hostname(VM name) of App service from kudu console
>hostname
R***********

--Using Azure CLI to get the host's encryption status
>az vm encryption show -g "myResourceGroupName" -n "R***********"

Getting error "The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/R******' under resource group 'myResourceGroupName' was not found. For more details please go to https://*******ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
```

Any pointers on getting this encryption status correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get the hosted VM's encryption status. The VMs are managed by Azure, you could not access them directly.

The CLI command you used calls the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get), it just gets the VM in your subscription whose resource type is `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines`.

Answer (score 0):

App Services are a PaaS offering as such you as a subscriber do not have any access or control over the underlying components. Even if you are using Isolated mode or deploying within an ASE where the resources are dedicated.
All storage is encrypted at rest using the azure standard encryption service and Microsoft manged keys.